# Has anyone been able to get SharePoint using NTLM working with SQUID as a reverse proxy?

Tags: sharepoint, ntlm, squid

1. We have a SQUID reverse proxy and a MOSS 2007 portal. All sites are using NTLM.
2. We cannot get it working with SQUID as a reverse proxy.

Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you switch to Kerberos instead of NTLM?

You're encountering the "Double-Hop Issue", whereby NTLM authentication cannot traverse proxies or servers.

This is outlined at this location:
http://blogs.msdn.com/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx

And over here:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;329986

> Double-Hop Issue
>   The double-hop issue is when the ASPX page tries to use resources that are located on a server that is different from the IIS server. In our case, the first "hop" is from the web browser client to the IIS ASPX page; the second hop is to the AD. The AD requires a primary token. Therefore, the IIS server must know the password for the client to pass a primary token to the AD. If the IIS server has a secondary token, the NTAUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS account credentials are used. This account is not a domain account and has very limited access to the AD.
>
> The double-hop using a secondary token occurs, for example, when the browser client is authenticated to the IIS ASPX page by using NTLM authentication. In this example, the IIS server has a hashed version of the password as a result of using NTLM. If IIS turns around and passes the credentials to the AD, IIS is passing a hashed password. The AD cannot verify the password and, instead, authenticates by using the NTAUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON.
>
> On the other hand, if your browser client is authenticated to the IIS ASPX page by using Basic authentication, the IIS server has the client password and can make a primary token to pass to the AD. The AD can verify the password and does authenticate as the domain user.
>   For more information, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>   264921 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264921/) How IIS authenticates browser clients

If switching to Kerberos is not an option, have you investigated the Squid NTLM project?
http://devel.squid-cache.org/ntlm/

Answer (score -1):

you can use HAProxy for load balancing

Comment: How is that going to help here?

Comment: reverse proxy often used for load balancing , I propose to use for this other product